# Identical values in an array has to be positioned together

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var array1 = ["ddd","aaa","eee","aaa","fff","bbb","ggg","aaa","ccc","fff"]
```

i have to arrange it in a way that  identical values has to be placed together

output array should be

```
["ddd","aaa","aaa","aaa","eee","fff","fff","bbb","ggg","ccc"]
```

how to write the logic for this one ??

Comment: Just sort it...?

Comment: 1) What have you tried? 2) Does the order matter? Could you have the `"aaa"` results in the front?

Comment: We're not here to write the code for you. Try to approach the problem, and if you get stuck, post your attempted solution along with what's going wrong.

Comment: @crowder I tried on my own when I found it difficult I posted this code .  first I tried to seperare  the repeated element and then to merge it with old  in a new array . here the array is going to be array of customer objects      for(var i=0 ; i<cusData.length ; i++){
  if(cusData[i].dup == "true"){
  tempCustData.push(cusData[i]);
   cusData.pop();
}
} for(var x=0 ; x<tempCusData.length ; x++){
  for(var y=0 ; y<cusData.length ; y++){
// finalCusData.push(cusData[0]); pushing data for all y
  if(tempCusData[0].name === cusData[0].name){
  finalCusData.push(tempCusData[0]);
}
}
}

Comment: @crowder I  thought creating two arrays and iterating this many times will affect the performance that's y I posted the question

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate the array and check the position and if not the same as the actual element, splice the value to the earlier position.

```js
var array = ["ddd","aaa","eee","aaa","fff","bbb","ggg","aaa","ccc","fff"],
    i = 0, p;
    
while (i < array.length) {
    p = array.indexOf(array[i]);
    if (p !== i) {
        array.splice(p, 0, array.splice(i, 1)[0]);
    }
    i++;
}

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sort array using `sort()` method like this

```js
var array1 = ["ddd","aaa","eee","aaa","fff","bbb","ggg","aaa","ccc","fff"];

console.log(array1.sort());
```

Answer (score 0):

Well actually for you request `.sort()` might be an overkill. You can simply do this by;

```js
function quasiSort(a){
  var h = a.reduce((h,e) => h[e] ? (h[e].push(e), h)
                                 : (h[e] = [e], h), {});
  return Object.keys(h).reduce((r,k) => r.concat(h[k]),[]);
}
var array1 = ["ddd","aaa","eee","aaa","fff","bbb","ggg","aaa","ccc","fff"];
console.log(quasiSort(array1));
```

Comment: This works like a charm ..  This function is very new to me . can you please explain how its working if you don't @redu

Comment: @ani Happy that you have sorted out. Just let me know if you have any further questions.

Comment: can please explain how this function is working.. Hope it will definitely help others also ..

Comment: can you please tell me how to use this method for grouping array of objects (e.g) var friends = [{
  name: 'Anna',
  books: ['Bible', 'Harry Potter'],
  age: 21
}, {
  name: 'Bob',
  books: ['War and peace', 'Romeo and Juliet'],
  age: 26
}, {
  name: 'Alice',
  books: ['The Lord of the Rings', 'The Shining'],
  age: 18
},name: 'Anna',
  books: ['Bible', 'Alice in wonderland'],
  age: 23];

Comment: @ani It can be done but according to which property of the object you would like to group.. `name`?

Comment: @ani Please check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43139954/4543207) up.

Answer (score 0):

You can create one object to store values and index and then use that object to create new array.

```js
var array1 = ["ddd","aaa","eee","aaa","fff","bbb","ggg","aaa","ccc","fff"],
 obj = {}, i = 0

array1.forEach(function(e) {
  if(!obj[e]) obj[e] = {index: i++, values: []}
  obj[e].values.push(e)
})

var result = [].concat(...Object.keys(obj).reduce((r, e) => (r[obj[e].index] = obj[e].values, r), []))

console.log(result)
```

Comment: can you please explain your answer. I just want to understand how this reduce () is working