# javascript - grouping objects by properties

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

my question is somewhat similar to [javascript | Object grouping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21776389/javascript-object-grouping) .

my input obj is

```
[
  {
    "name":"Display",
    "group":"Technical detals",
    "id":"60",
    "value":"4"
  },
  {
    "name":"Manufacturer",
    "group":"Manufacturer",
    "id":"58",
    "value":"Apple"
  },
  {
    "name":"OS",
    "group":"Technical detals",
    "id":"37",
    "value":"Apple iOS"
  }
]
```

and my required output is

```
 [
  {
    "name":"Display",
    "group":"Technical detals",
    "id":"60",
    "value":"4"
  },
  {
    "name":"OS",
    "group":"Technical detals",
    "id":"37",
    "value":"Apple iOS"
  },
  {
    "name":"Manufacturer",
    "group":"Manufacturer",
    "id":"58",
    "value":"Apple"
  }

]
```

when i tried to implement the answer ,i got

```
[[[object Object] {
  group: "Technical detals",
  id: "60",
  name: "Display",
  value: "4"
}, [object Object] {
  group: "Technical detals",
  id: "37",
  name: "OS",
  value: "Apple iOS"
}], [[object Object] {
  group: "Manufacturer",
  id: "58",
  name: "Manufacturer",
  value: "Apple"
}]]
```

i don't want to group my objects with same property into a single array .  i couldn't find out where they are pushing it into array. help me to Fix it :(

Comment: what is the difference between input and output, despite of the order?

Comment: It is not grouping, it is sorting.

Comment: Are you trying to sort your array ? based on which property ?

Comment: No . I am trying to group the objects . something like all objects that comes under group technical details should be placed next to next so that when I display it in table all the items will be in next next row

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could group the items and the concat all groups in a single array.

> It works by generating an object with the group as property an the items as items in the array.
>
> In the next step, the object's values are taken and a new array is generated by concatination of the items with [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).
>
> ```
> {                                                                              // hash
>     "Technical detals": [
>         {
>             name: "Display",
>             group: "Technical detals",
>             id: "60",
>             value: "4"
>         },
>         {
>             name: "OS",
>             group: "Technical detals",
>             id: "37",
>             value: "Apple iOS"
>         }
>     ],
>     Manufacturer: [
>         {
>             name: "Manufacturer",
>             group: "Manufacturer",
>             id: "58",
>             value: "Apple"
>         }
>     ]
> }
> ```

```js
var data = [{ name: "Display", group: "Technical detals", id: "60", value: "4" }, { name: "Manufacturer", group: "Manufacturer", id: "58", value: "Apple" }, { name: "OS", group: "Technical detals", id: "37", value: "Apple iOS" }],
    groups = Object.create(null),
    result = [];

data.forEach(function (a) {
    groups[a.group] = groups[a.group] || [];
    groups[a.group].push(a);    
});

result = Object.keys(groups).reduce(function (r, k) {
    return r.concat(groups[k]);
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Or just sort by `group`.

```js
var data = [{ name: "Display", group: "Technical detals", id: "60", value: "4" }, { name: "Manufacturer", group: "Manufacturer", id: "58", value: "Apple" }, { name: "OS", group: "Technical detals", id: "37", value: "Apple iOS" }];

data.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.group.localeCompare(b.group);
});

console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: perfect one !! Can you elaborate the steps you actually performing .. Everything seems Greek and Latin to me

Answer (score 0):

Without sorting you may group by the provided property (`by`) as follows;

```js
function quasiSort(a,by){
  var h = a.reduce((h,e) => h[e[by]] ? (h[e[by]].push(e), h)
                                     : (h[e[by]] = [e], h), {});
  return Object.keys(h).reduce((r,k) => r.concat(h[k]),[]);
}
var data = [{ "name":"Display",
             "group":"Technical detals",
                "id":"60",
             "value":"4"
            },
            { "name":"Manufacturer",
             "group":"Manufacturer",
                "id":"58",
             "value":"Apple"
            },
            { "name":"OS",
             "group":"Technical detals",
                "id":"37",
             "value":"Apple iOS"
            }
           ];
           
console.log(quasiSort(data,"group"));
```